# Remote registry change HKCU using only cmd and psexec

Tags: cmd, registry, psexec

Hi everyone I am lost...

I have admin rights.

I want to modify registry key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software.... on remote PC where another user is logged.

I don't want to use PowerShell because we don't have remote registry enabled.

I am stuck with cmd

Therefore I use PSexec.

If I want to change something in global HKLM its pretty easy

```
psexec \\COMPUTERNAME reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\...... /t REG_DWORD
```

since I call the psexec as admin it allows me to change anything in HKLM on the remote machine

but when I need to change something in HKCU I need the SID of the user to plug it into HKEY_USERS\SID\SOFTWARE\ and that's where I hit a wall...

I tried something like this (it didn't work, the syntax is probably all wrong)

```
psexec \\COMPUTERNAME for /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%i in ('query user') do set varusername=%%i
```

this was supposed to get remote logged users name into variable 'varusername' to later use it to get SID

something like this (again the syntax is probably wrong):

```
psexec \\COMPUTERNAME wmic useraccount where name='%varusername%' get sid
```

this completely blew up since wmic on the remote computer when executed as admin (via psexec) doesn't see the same users as query user...

here is the output of the respective commands

**query user** give me the logged user name 'johndoe'

USERNAME     SESSIONNAME     ID     STATE    IDLE     TIME    LOGON TIME

johndoe      console      1        Active        none      9/10/2018 5:27

**wmic useraccount get name, sid** does not see the 'johndoe' at all

Name            SID

DefaultAccount  S-1-5-21-3285310242-2953612481-1302521585-503

defaultuser0    S-1-5-21-3285310242-2953612481-1302521585-1002

LocalAdmin      S-1-5-21-3285310242-2953612481-1302521585-500

Guest           S-1-5-21-3285310242-2953612481-1302521585-501

so as you can see I hit the wall

**query user** gives me logged user on remote PC "johndoe" but I have no way to get SID of "johndoe" using **wmic useraccount** to plug it into:

```
psexec \\COMPUTERNAME reg add HKEY_USERS\SID\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\...... /t REG_DWORD
```

any ideas how to get around this?

I just need to edit HKCU on remote PC for a currently logged user without using PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you have access to PowerShell, you may be able to use it to get the SID, to then run PSExec on your machine. Try running:

```
Get-AdUser USERNAME -Properties SID | Select name,Sid
```

in PowerShell, replacing USERNAME with the person's username you're trying to edit.

This should get the SID from the active directory, as local commands such as WMIC will not get what you are looking for.

Once you have the SID, you can whack it in your PSExec command and let loose the angels of hell.

I mention using PowerShell because even without remote registry enabled, you should be able to run this command as a System Administrator. If not, you can also just go into the Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd you can get the SID with [`PsGetSid`](https://documentation.help/PsTools/PsGetSid.htm).

I'm trying the same process as admin..

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Reg load HKCU\UserTemp c:\users\<username>\NTUSER.DAT
```

And:

```
Reg unload HKCU\UserTemp
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your target PC works in AD infrastructure.

This example demonstrates 3 main steps:

- search for logged user - `WMIC path Win32_LogonSession`
- get user domain and user login name - `WMIC path Win32_LoggedonUser`
- finally search for user's `SID` - `WMIC path Win32_UserAccount`

P.S. If you plan to work with multiple users on terminal server make subroutine to work with many `LogonId` values - `%Id%` variable.

P.P.S.
This example searches for two type of [logged on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logonsession) users: Network (3) or RemoteInteractive (10): `LogonType` value in first line.

```
FOR /f "skip=1" %%i in ('WMIC path Win32_LogonSession where "LogonType=3 or LogonType=10" get LogonId ^|  findstr /r /v "^$" ') DO SET "Id=%%i"

FOR /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2,3 delims== " %%a in (`WMIC path Win32_LoggedonUser where " Dependent = '\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId="%Id%"' " get Antecedent`) DO SET "User=%%a%%b"
FOR /f tokens^=1-3^ delims^=^" %%a in ("%User%") do SET "domain=%%a" & set "User=%%c"

FOR /f "usebackq skip=1 " %%a in (`WMIC path Win32_UserAccount where " name='%user%' and domain='%Domain%' " get sid ^|  findstr /r /v "^$" `) DO SET "sid=%%a"

@echo %sid%
```